# If I only want to use part of a can of beans, what are my options with the rest?

Tags: beans

I typically cook eggs in the morning, and would like to add some legumes to add a little more heft. I'm looking for the easiest way to do this, so I thought of canned beans. However, I don't think I want the full can. What can I do with the rest so that I can use them the next day or two?

Answer (score 7):

As rfusca says, they'll be fine for a few days in the fridge; HOWEVER, if you want to transform them into something more delicious and less perishable to go with eggs,  you can cook them into black bean fritters.

First, cook the beans with garlic, minced onion, and chile powder to soften them.  Mash or puree, and reduce until thick, then add salt. Done right, this can be pan-fried into something delicious to go with eggs.  Probably one of my favorite breakfast items from a summer in Guatemala.

Depending on how much water you remove from the fritter base, it should be fine in the fridge for 3 days to a week. It can also be shaped into patties, stacked between layers of wax paper or baking parchment, and frozen indefinitely.

Comment: You may want to mention expected storage and shelf life after making the fritter.

Comment: @rfusca: I've edited in an answer.  If cooked until fairly dry, salted heavily, or acidified with vinegar, fritter base could be fine for more than a week.

Comment: Awesome +1 - an option for more favor.  He had mentioned the "easiest way to do this" so I had avoided transforming the dish, but this is certainly easy!

Answer (score 4):

For a day or two?  Put them covered in the fridge. (By covered, I mean in a some sort of plastic or glass, reusable container or whatever you have on hand for storing items in the fridge - do remove them from the can.)

Comment: I'd take them all out of the can first, they seem to last a little longer when in a proper container.

Comment: @Aaronut - Indeed, more explicit posted.